# How to get the NT login from an AD UserPrincpal object?

Tags: c#, active-directory

Consider the following simplied code sample:

```
Principal p = .. // from business logic
UserPrincipal user = (p as UserPrincipal);
```

How can I get the NT login for the user. i.e. : DOMAIN\UserName

Answer (score 2):

The username component you can get from `user.SamAccountName`. The domain component is not nearly as easy as it's not actually an attribute of the user.

What is probably easiest is to get the user's SID and then use the NTAccount class to crack it. Something like this should work - I just typed it out here though so might need to tweak it a bit:

```
DirectoryEntry rawEntry = user.GetUnderlyingObject();
byte[] sidBytes = (byte[])user.Properties["objectSID"].Value;

SecurityIdentifier mySid = new SecurityIdentifier(sidBytes, 0);

NTAccount ntAccount = (NTAccount)mySid.Translate(typeof(NTAccount));

string domainWhackUsername = ntAccount.ToString();
```